# PHP execution (command line vs web) of apache_get_version()

Tags: php

I'm calling the apache_get_version() function in my php script. When I execute the script via web url everything works fine. I got the output I expected.

When calling the script from command line ("php index.php") I recieve an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_get_version()
```

Does anyone know why this happens? The version is always PHP 5.5.12 and it seems as it has nothing to do with privileges since I execute the script as root from the command line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because on the command line apache is not involved/needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I execute the script as root from the command line

The `apache_get_version` function is only available when the script is run through Apache.

You can see [the manual page](http://php.net/apache_get_version) listed under *server specific extensions* and [the introduction page for that section](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php) says:

> These functions are only available when running PHP as an Apache module.